# using set variable in copy command

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

How can I copy a file inside a bat file using a set variable.

[run.bat]

```
set MY_WORKSPACE=workspace1.0.1
copy /Y /V D:\%MY_WORKSPACE%\webapp\target\app-generic.war C:\Opt\jboss-4.2.3.GA\server\default\deploy\
```

In above example, %MY_WORKSPACE% is invalid, however I can see the value by using 'echo'

Comment: Your syntax is absolutely correct.  Both the "set", as well as the "%MY_WORKSPACE%".  Q: Do you actually have a directory "d:\workspace1.0.1"?  Q: What is the exact error you're getting?

Comment: Like Joey asked: Q: Is that the whole batch file you're showing us?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that the whole batch file you're showing us?

I have a vague feeling you're doing the `set` and `copy` inside an `if` or similar statement with a block, e.g.

```
if foo==bar (
  set MY_WORKSPACE=workspace1.0.1
  copy ...
)
```

In this case you need delayed expansion for the variable change to take effect because the block in parentheses is parsed as a single command and all variables are substituted at *parse* time, not when runnin a command. Therefore `%MY_WORKSPACE%` will be empty once the block runs.

You can solve this by using

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

at the top of your batch file and using `!MY_WORKSPACE!` instead of `%MY_WORKSPACE%` which will expand the variable just prior to running the command, not while parsing.

Comment: +1 I believe it is more than a "vague" feeling, considering this is one of the most common root causes of problems that people have with batch files :-)

Comment: It's almost always the answer to »I'm setting the variable but the value doesn't get picked up by the line after it« ;-)

Comment: Thanks Joey... that setlocal fixed the problem. you were right it was inside the if-block

Comment: Mwahaha! Once again my psychic powers save the day!

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
set MY_WORKSPACE="workspace1.0.1"
```